# How to work with the @removed annotation of Event objects in MS graph using the Java Sdk

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the beta SDK to get event deltas:

```
    mGraphServiceController.getEventsDelta(mDeltaLink).get()
```

For deleted events I get a response like this:

```
    {
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(event)",
"@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events/delta?$deltatoken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.event",
        "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "@removed": {
            "reason": "deleted"
        }
    }
]
    }
```

How can I access the @removed annotation using the MS graph Java SDK (beta) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@removed` object can accessed via the `additionalDataManager()` method of the `com.microsoft.graph.models.Event`.

Here is a sample code in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val events = graphApiClient.me()
            .calendarView()
            .delta()
            .buildRequest(requestOptions)
            .get()
val event = events.currentPage.first()
val isRemovedEvent = event.additionalDataManager().contains("@removed")
```

More about the `@removed` object in [the Microsoft Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#resource-representation-in-the-delta-query-response)